# Date range for backfill between two dates in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I want to backfill from a particular date to the latest date(say last working day).
Considering I have total 671 partitions

```
count .Q.pv / 671j
```

And we need to backfill for last 10 days

```
{//backfill function; 0n!x}@'660 11 sublist .Q.pv
```

Is there any other/better way to provide partition dates to backfill function other then using sublist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-10#date` to get last 10 dates in your hdb.

Another "safer" option would be to use sublist as this will work in the occurrence of you having less than 10 dates in your hdb:
`-10 sublist date`

Answer (score 1):

To list all dates between two dates you could use the following formula;

```
q)daterange:{[date1;date2] 1+date1+til date2-date1}
q)daterange[2019.05.29;2019.06.03]
2019.05.30 2019.05.31 2019.06.01 2019.06.02 2019.06.03
```

This will increment from date1 until as many days as there are between date1 and date2.

Hope this helps